# How to solve Log shipping issues when Shadow copy volume-level backups are in place?

Tags: log-shipping, log, snapshot, vss

How to solve Log shipping issues when Shadow copy volume-level backups are in place? I tried setting up log shipping but it failed each time because the  backup chain of the virtual log, the block number and the LSn log backups were different after the VSS ran it's snapshot. As a result the log shipping failed. I tried restoring the log to resume log shipping operation but I get this error “The file is too recent to apply to the secondary database”

Comment: Do you know what is taking VSS Snapshots, and do you have control to make changes to those backups?

Comment: Yes, the backup is in Azure VSS Shadow Copy SQL Writer, as far as access to Azure  another team runs the backups.